How non-signal values notify angular for updating the component's UI
Custom services in Angular can have either signal based or non-signal based properties. In case of signal based properties, if they update, angular ensures to notify the component (which injects such a service, and is consuming some content from service which can be updated by the service) about such data updates and hence updates the UI.
But, if services have non-signal based properties, and then if any data change happens in the service, then too the UI of the component IS updated. Can anyone kindly explain that if we use non-signal values in service, then how the component gets to know that it needs to recompute the data values on data updates by the service ?

There'e a lot of articles related to "angular change detection", e.g. this link. NOTE: the "signal" is pretty new (It was available only from Angular 16), so the other mechanism was the only one before)

Are you using change detection strategy Default or OnPush?

In short, the component doesn't know. Something has to trigger the change detection.
Even in the case of ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default, it doesn't know. Just because there are usually so many triggers throughout the app, the value from the service will eventually be updated too.
If you are familiar with change detection, I encourage you to read all 4 articles about performance in Angular docs, then create a small app, and play with change detection for yourself.
